# Git commits log information in a wrong order

Tags: git

I am a new in the field of Git. I tried to use `git commit` to log my software different versions. However, I get the following result.

```
60cf510 (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{0}: commit: Automatically detect whether use the fix effect to make the final prediction
791df2d HEAD@{1}: commit: release version 1.0
f9a3697 HEAD@{2}: commit: Add colmun selection in covariate and phenotype
889b11b HEAD@{3}: commit: Add preprocess (overlap, snp order, flip allele)
8c7688f HEAD@{4}: commit (initial): Fix bug in estimating delta and add flip minor allel
```

The log with hash code `60cf510` is my newest submit. I think this log information should follow the `8c7688f`. I am not sure what the problem is. What's more, I do not know why the `commit (initial)` exists. Is it because I reinitialize the git? Thank you.

The following message come from the command `git log`.

```
commit 60cf510c9b549b6a1f89fc7b3ba2f88faca7a8fa (HEAD -> master)
Author: shunkang <shunkang1997@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Feb 18 22:57:45 2020 +0800

    Automatically detect whether use the fix effect to make the final prediction

    If there is no prediction covariate file provided, the software will only use the random effect to make the prediction. The final output result will show two columns with the same value.

commit 791df2d446ed8db87751620c48d15beac04074ce
Author: shunkang <shunkang1997@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Nov 21 11:43:11 2019 +0800

    release version 1.0

commit f9a3697960f27648e7fbe86ad1e64072ea34888a
Author: shunkang <shunkang1997@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Nov 21 11:10:57 2019 +0800

    Add colmun selection in covariate and phenotype

commit 889b11b7aa4c9db9a3feb3b2f6691cd64559b46b
:
```

Comment: My guess is that you did a `git pull` before making the latest commit, which brought in those 3 other commits.

Comment: You said you expect to see `8c7688f`, but also that you don't know why it exists. Do you mean "why is it marked (initial) ?" Did you expect to see something else there? Why are you "using git commit to log ..." instead of using `git log` to log?

Comment: The output you show here is from `git reflog`. That shows the contents of the *reflog* for `HEAD`, which is not at all the same as the *commits in the repository*. It seems likely that you are using the wrong `git` command here.

Comment: @Useless I mean I just the `git commit -m` to add the log information.

Comment: @torek I also add the message from command `git log`. Actually, I first submitted two log information and then commit the last one. However, the last one I submitted log is  located on the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything here looks quite normal.

We might start with these observations:

- Git stores, for the most part, *commits*.  That is, the commit is the basic unit of Git storage.  (It's possible to break a commit into several parts, and Git sometimes does, but mostly we work with whole commits at a time.)
- As each commit is created, it acquires a unique *hash ID*.  This hash ID is forever reserved for *this* commit, not only in *this* Git repository, but in *every* Git repository everywhere.  In a sense, it was reserved for this even *before* you made the commit, except for the fact that the commit hash ID depends on the time, down to the second, *when* you make the commit.

  (These hash IDs are very big and unwieldy.  They have to be, to be unique like this.  No *human* can get them right, but that's OK: we have a *computer*, after all.)
- Each commit holds a snapshot of *all* of your files.  That's the main *data* within a commit, but each commit also holds some *metadata:* some information about the commit itself.  The metadata includes the name and email address of whoever made it—as two entries, *author* and *committer*—and some date-and-time stamps, and a log message where you, or whoever, record the *reason* you made the commit.

  A key item in this metadata, though, is that each commit stores the actual hash ID of its immediate predecessor commit or commits.  That is, each commit has some number of *parent* commits—usually just one—and the child commit stores the raw hash ID of its parent or parents.

Whenever we have, stored somewhere, the hash ID of a commit, we say that whatever it is that holds this hash ID *points to* the commit.  So if you have some hash ID *H* written down somewhere—on paper or on a whitebord, for instance—we might say that this *points to* commit `H`.  Since each commit stores the hash ID of its parent, each commit *points to* its parent.  We can draw this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where `H` is some commit with some hash ID *H*, and it points to its parent `G`, which in turn points to its parent `F`, and so on.

If we record the *last* hash ID of some long chain of commits in a *branch name* like `master`, that suffices for Git to find *all* of those commits.  The name points to the last commit:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

and from there, Git can work backwards: starting at `H`, it finds `G`, then `F`, and so on.  This repeats until Git finds the very first commit ever made, which doesn't point back any further, because it can't.

To make a new commit, we start by extracting commit `H` into a work area.  (All commits are 100% read-only, so we cannot change `H`, but we can change the stuff we copy to a work area.)  Then we edit files as usual, use `git add` to copy them to the *index*—another key item but we won't go into the details here—and use `git commit` to make a new commit.  Git packages up *all* of our files into a new snapshot, adds the metadata—our name and email address and the current date and time, for instance—and sets the parent of the *new* commit to be commit `H`.  This new commit acquires its new ID, which is too big for us to manage but we'll just call it `I`.  New commit `I` therefore points back to existing commit `H`.

As its final act, `git commit` *writes the hash ID of the new commit into the current branch name*.  If the current branch name is `master`, Git writes `I`'s hash ID into `master`, so that `master` now points to `I`.  Since `I` points back to `H`, that's what we get:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
```

#### The `git log` command starts at the end and works backwards

A regular `git log`—*not* `git reflog`!—starts from some ending-point commit hash ID, such as by looking inside the name `master`.  Whenever `git log` looks in a *branch name*, this is, by definition, the *last* commit in the branch.<sup>1</sup>  Then `git log` shows us this commit–commit `I`, in this case—and now `git log` simply moves on to the commit's parent.  So the *next* commit you *see* is the *previous commit*.

The log, in other words, automatically works *backwards*, from the end to the beginning.  This is a theme in Git: all of its internal arrows point backwards.  Git always has to start at the end and work backwards.  So `git log` shows the newest commit by default, because by default, it starts from your current branch name, which is the newest commit on that branch.

Note that if you use `git checkout`—or the new Git 2.23+ `git switch`—to switch to a different branch name, `git log` will start from that other branch name, rather than from `master`.  Or, if you use `git checkout` or `git switch` to switch to *detached HEAD* mode, in which the special name `HEAD` points directly to a commit, `git log` will default to starting from that historical commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>The definition of a branch name is that it holds the hash ID of the *last* commit.  That's what `git branch -f`, `git reset`, and so on can do: by forcing a *different* hash ID into a branch name, this changes *which commit is the last commit*.  That's also why `git commit` writes the new commit's hash ID into the branch name: this new commit is, by definition, the *last* commit, and by definition, a branch name *must* hold the hash ID of the *last* commit, so `git commit` keeps the two definitions working together.

---

#### When `git log` is more complicated

It's often important to *draw the graph* of commits, by drawing each commit and an arrow from it to its parent(s):

```
          I--J   <-- branch1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

Here we have two different branch names, each pointing to one commit—`J` for `branch1` and `L` for `branch2`—with their one commit pointing backwards as usual, but at some point, the two branches *join up* in history: commits `I` and `K` *both* point back to commit `H`.

The `git log` command normally starts from the *current branch tip* and works backwards.  If we pick `branch1` as our current branch, for instance, we'll see commit `J` first, then `I`, then `H`, then `G`, and so on.  If we pick `branch2` as our current branch, we'll see `L`, then `K`, then `H`, and so on.  Note that either way, we *don't* see two of these commits.

We can, however, tell `git log` to start from *both* `branch1` *and* `branch2`.  But `git log` can only show *one commit at a time*.  Will it show us `J` first, or `L` first?

The answer to this question is complicated.  Sometimes Git will show us `J` first, and sometimes it will show `L` first.  To pick one of the two, `git log` puts *both* commits into a [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).  The default priority is by *committer date-and-time*, so that whichever of `J` or `L` was made *later* is the one we'll see first.  You can give `git log` different sort options, which change the priority; in this case, you might see the other commit first.

Having taken one of the two commits out of the queue and shown it, `git log` will now put that commit's parent into the priority queue.  It will then show you the highest priority commit—whichever one that is—next.  Then it will put *that* commit's parent into the priority queue.  There are still two commits in this queue, so once again, which commit you see after these first two is determined by the priority queue.

Eventually, it's likely—or, depending on the flags you give `git log`, *necessary*—that `git log` will have shown `J`, `I`, `L`, and `K` *before* showing commit `H`.  At this point only commit `H` itself will be in the priority queue, so `git log` will now show `H` and put commit `G` in the queue.  Now `G` will be the only commit in the queue, so `git log` will show `G`, and put `G`'s parent in the queue, and so on.

In other words, `git log` *sometimes* **sorts** commits.  It does this **only when its priority queue has more than one entry in it**, which happens automatically if you give it multiple starting point commits, such as `J` and `L` here.  But look what happens after we *merge* some commits:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M--N   <-- master
         \    /
          K--L
```

Now, if we start at `master` and work back, `git log` *must* show `N` first—that's the only commit in the queue—and then `M`.  But commit `M` has *two* parents, so `git log` now puts both `J` and `L` into the queue.  Now it has two commits to show, so it picks one, based on priority.  In other words, it now *sorts* the commits according to the options we give it.  We're back in the same situation we had when we had two branch names, pointing to commits `J` and `L`, and told `git log` to show both commits / branches.

#### `git log` shows us one commit at a time, even if history is more complex

The history we'll see from `git log` can be misleading.  It might show us `N`, then `M`, then `L` and `K, then` I`and`J`, in that order.  If we're not aware of the fact that there was a branch-and-merge, we might think that the commits were made linearly like that.

For this reason, you can have `git log` draw a crude text-based graph.  This graph is not always very pretty, but it will show that commits `L` and `K` are *parallel to* commits `J` and `I`: that they form a branch-and-merge structure in the history, as recorded in the commits.

#### History is commits; commits are history

Note that throughout all these processes, no *commit* changes.  We can view the commits one at a time, in different orders with `git log --sort=...` or `git log --topo-order`, and/or have Git draw a graph with `git log --graph`.  Or, we can draw our graph on a whiteboard, or on paper, or using various graph-drawing programs.  But whatever we do, the *commits themselves* never change.  These commits *are* the history in your repository.  Their connections exist from the moment you make the commits: child commits point back to their parents.  Merge commits are commits with two (or more) parents.  Branches "fork" when a parent has two or more children.

You can always *add more commits* to the graph.  Git *finds* commits by using branch names, which by definition are the *last* commit in that branch.  You can always add new branch names, and you can delete branch names as well.  If you delete the *only* name that allows you to *find* some commit—for instance, if you have:

```
...--o--o--o--o--...--o  <-- master
         \
          H   <-- branch
```

and you delete the name `branch`—that one particular commit, in this case `H`, becomes hard, or maybe impossible, to *find*.  However, Git has other ways to find commits.  For instance, *tag names* can point to commits.  Git also keeps a *log* of previous values of particular branch and other names.  This log, called a *reflog*, could allow you to find commit `H`.

Some operations, such as `git rebase`, work by *copying* an existing series of commits to new and improved commits, then moving a branch name.  Since the name holds the hash ID of the *last* commit, if we copy the commits and then move the *name*, it looks like we somehow changed the commits:

```
...--o--o--o--o--...--o  <-- master
         \
          H--I--J   <-- branch
```

becomes:

```
...--o--o--o--o--...--o  <-- master
         \             \
          H--I--J       H'-I'-J'  <-- branch
```

where `H'` is the copy of `H`, `I'` is the copy of `I`, and `J'` is the copy of `J`.  We didn't actually *change* the commits though.  The originals are still there, in the repository.  You just can't *find* them easily, because we start with the *name* `branch` to *find* commit `I'` now, and work backwards from there.

(The reflog for the name `branch` holds the hash ID of commit `J`.  If we decide we wish to "undo" the rebase operation, we can force the name `branch` to remember `J` again, instead of `J'`.  Then the reflog for `branch` will hold the hash ID of commit `J'`.  Since reflogs hold multiple entries, we'll end up with multiple reflog entries holding `J` and/or `J'`.  The reflog entries eventually *expire* though, so *eventually* we'll forget commit `J` entirely, as long as the name `branch` points only to `J'`.  A branch name can only point to *one* commit, and in fact, *must* point to *one* commit at all times.)